# Correlated Walk Analysis PHP - Algorithm PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, math, analysis

I'm currently building a PHP based social media crime analysis website for a university project.
I'm very keen on including the 'correlated walk analysis' technique into my website.

This technique is detailed here on page 14: http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/files/CrimeStatChapter.9.pdf

It specifies this algorithm: (E(d) = drms * sqrt N)
I can't post images so here's the link to the image:

[image]

I was wondering **what the best way/technique is to get this into PHP** - if it is at all possible? I have access to my own server.

I have grabbed a large amount of location data from social media, so assume I have enough data to complete the algorithm.

Comment: using php for alot of calculating is not the best idea. most likely you will have a timeout after 30 secs. ofcourse you can reset the timer and keep php going on.
Another way is to implement this native in C or what ever and run a shell command.

Comment: After a bit more research, I think using R with the crawl package might suffice: but this is a new area of research for myself